# No overload for method 'ToString" takes 1 arguments when casting date

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, datetime

I am trying to save a date from my Angular ui-Datepicker to my SQL database.  The date is in the format (10-27-2015 12:00 AM) but it will not save.  I tried using the following to convert it to SQL DateTime format:

```
    DateTime? myDate = form.dteStartDate;
    string sqlFormattedDate = myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

But I receive the error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.  The field in SQL is type 'datetime'.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As your answer says, `myDate` isn't a `DateTime`, its a `Nullable<DateTime>`, so when you call `ToString` its calling it on the `Nullable<T>` type, not `DateTime`.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You want to use [`DateTime.ToString(format)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) not [`Nullable<DateTime>.ToString(no overload)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime? myDate = form.dteStartDate;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Of course this doesn't handle the case that there is no value. Perhaps something like this:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = myDate.HasValue 
    ? myDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    : "<not available>";
```

Comment: myDate.Value.HasValue will return error. It should be         myDate.HasValue ? startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Comment: If you can live with a little boxing behind the scenes, and if you want the empty string in case `myDate` is null, there is a short syntax possible with `string sqlFormattedDate = $"{myDate:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}";`. Requires C# 6 (interpolated strings). Works internally by boxing the wrapped `DateTime` to an `object` reference. If that becomes a null reference, the empty string is used. Otherwise, it is confirmed that the run-time type of the box implements `IFormattable`, and the relevant `ToString` overload from that interface is used.

Comment: I experienced the same problem in the survey solutions but adding .Value solved my problem. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 13):

The most immediate way to do this is to write:

```
DateTime? myDate = form.dteStartDate;    
string sqlFormattedDate = myDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") ?? "N/A";
```

adding ? after myDate will check if it is not null, and with the ?? you will handle the case in which the variable is null.

Answer (score 7):

It will work fine.

```
DateTime? strDate = form.dteStartDate;
strDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 string sqlFormattedDate = ((DateTime)myDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Also if you can use server-side code in `.cshtml` and manage this casting as below (for example):

```
   <label>Establish: @(((DateTime)Model.EstablishDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))</label>
```

Comment: This helped me. I did in .cshtml. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Another way is adding question mark behind "myDate" variable.

```
DateTime? myDate = form.dteStartDate;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```