# ASP.Net C# sqlDr.GetValue(a) Date Column Displaying Time too

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, date

I tried to use

```
 sqlDr.GetValue(a).ToString()
```

to display a DATE column from my database which looks like this..(the Date Submitted column)
[image]

But the problem is , when i display it using getValue(8).toString(), something like this is displayed..

[image]

Thanks for taking your time to read my post , any reply is much appreciated!

Comment: change it to `sqlDr.GetValue(a).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` this should fix it.

Comment: The problem is i have many columns and not just date, does other column works too if i do that? Thanks

Comment: it works on DateTime columns only. so if the other columns matches the same datatype, it should works fine, the following link should give you a good overview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @iSR5 Thanks, but i am getting another error after adding the line , 
(no overload for method 'ToString' Takes 1 arguments) Any Clue ?

Comment: perhaps your calling a nullable DateTime, review this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371527/no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-arguments-when-casting-date

Comment: Thanks everyone , i have solve it with this : 
((DateTime)sqlDr.GetValue(a)).ToShortDateString();

with the condition : 
 if (sqlDr.GetDataTypeName(a).Equals("date"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is .Net does not have a Date-only primitive type. Therefore the Sql Server `Date` column type maps to a full `DateTime` value in .Net, which always includes a time component. If you don't provide a time component, the `DateTime` struct will have a 0-value time component, which maps to `12:00:00.000 AM`.

To get around this, you need to specify the output format for your column, so that it explicitly does not include a time value. You want something like this:

```
 ((DateTime)getValue(8)).ToString("d")
```

However, the exact code you need will vary wildly depending on how your result table is created. If necessary, check the [`SqlDataReader.GetDataTypeName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatatypename) function to know what type you're dealing with.

Comment: but the problem is now i am currently displaying from dynamic table , as i would not know which value is date ,
my code is something like this currently.

   html += "<tr>";

                for (int a = 0; a< (list.Count - 1); a++) { 
              
                html += "<td>" + sqlDr.GetValue(a).ToString() + "</td>";

                }
                html += "</tr>";

Thanks

Comment: Try using the [`SqlDataReader.GetDataTypeName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatatypename) method to check the type so you can format it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [DateTime.ToShortTimeString Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("Short date string:  \"{0}\"\n", myDateTime.ToShortDateString());
```

Output: Short date string:  "5/16/2001"