# ASP.NET MVC ToString error when converting a DateTime to a month number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am confused with the error I am getting. 
I am trying to return records that have the Month number equal to `i` but I recieve the following error.

```
    No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments
```

Is there another way to return month numbers from this table

```
 var ColourDates = Model.Color.Any(e => e.StartDate.ToString("MM") == i);
```

Comment: What is the type of `StartDate`?

Comment: It is a nullable datetime `DateTime?`

Comment: If it's nullable, you should probably use: `e.StartDate.HasValue ? e.StartDate.Value.ToString("MM") : ""`, but I'm assuming `i` is a `string`. Otherwise you should just use the `Month` property.

Comment: As documented, [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Nullable_1_ToString) does not have an overload of the `ToString` method which takes a parameter. You can reference the `Value` property which will return the underlying `DateTime`, but you need to deal with `null`s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No overload for method 'ToString" takes 1 arguments when casting date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371527/no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-arguments-when-casting-date)

Comment: @itsme86 i is a int. So How would I convert the Date time to return the month number as an int?

Comment: You don't need to convert it. There's a `Month` property. Just use `StartDate.Value.Month`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Nullable` types, you will need to get the value of the variable before use. You will need something like `var ColourDates = Model.Color.Any(e => e.StartDate.Value.ToString("MM") == i);`

NOTE: This does NOT handle null values. You will get an exception if `e.StartDate.Value` is null. I highly recommend using `e.StartDate.HasValue` to do a null check before use.