# How do I parse date and time from timestamp in view file(.cshtml) in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I thought it is simple thing but googling and researching for more than 2 hours still could not find answer. I have my timestamp (datatype is DateTime) in the model @item.arrival. And I have 2 columns in my web app where I have to separate date and time from the field @item.arrival and display it. I can access the field like this in my view file

```
<td>@item.arrival</td>
<td>@item.arrival</td>
```

But I don't how to separate date and time. The closest I got was separating using the html helper

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.arrival, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")</td>
```

But above code puts txt box in my page and I don't want that, I have my own styling in my page where i want to display my date and time in separate places. Any guidance is appreciated.

I am using asp.net mvc c# and I want to do this parsing in view and not in my controller.

Comment: try @item.arrival.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: @Atk i get error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say your `Nullable` property is defined like this

```
 public DateTime? arrival { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
```

*.cshtml*

```
<td>@item.arrival.Date.ToString("d")</td> //3/19/2020
<td>@item.arrival.ToString("HH:mm")</td> //23:15
```

*Update for handling Nullable, just add ? after the type*

```
<td>@item.arrival?.Date.ToString("d")</td> 
//If arrival is null it returns null else it will return Date
```

Comment: How is it possible to use "now" and "date" after the timestamp? yet I still tried and I got error so tried this <td>@item.arrival.ToString("d")</td> I am getting same error "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @Pal, I've updated the answer. Let me know if you understood the short hand notation that was introduced for brevity. I can explain otherwise

Answer (score 0):

@item.arrival.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") I have to use "value" inbetween since it is nullable datetime. Thank you everyone for the help. Much appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Use Below code

```
<td>@item.arrival.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</td>
<td>@item.arrival.ToString("hh:mm tt")</td>
```

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I tried this but it is showing error "No Overload for method 'ToString" takes 1 arguments." Not even allowing to build

Comment: Don't use Nullable datetime refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371527/no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-arguments-when-casting-date

Comment: Thank you Yes Nullable field is the problem

Comment: Niraj,  the answer you proposed is not accurate

Comment: @Pal what is this?

Comment: @Niraj Unfortunately I am not the subject matter expert. I did mark your as working.